# How to decline "Bekannte"?

Tags: word-usage, declension

I have a big problem specially with declining *"substantiviertes Adjektiv"* in all forms (nominative, genitive, dative and accusative) with definite and indefinite articles (bestimmte und unbestimmte Artikel).
For example "Bekannte" in Duden dictionary:

> die/eine Bekannte; der/einer Bekannten, die Bekannten/zwei Bekannte.

So why we have not "n" after *"Bekannte"* in *"zwei Bekannte"?* Is it plural?

Or why we have *"einer Bekannten"?* Is it dative in feminin? Why we use "n" after Bekannte" in this?

Comment: For your next post: Please read your own post and correct all errors before you publish your question. And do not mix German and English words! If you want to ask in English, please use English words only. If you want to use German terms, pack them into German sentences! I corrected all those errors for you, but please try to do it better next time.

Comment: The declension of nominalized adjectives is the same as the declension of non-nominalized adjectives. So please consult a declension table for adjectives, and pay attention to the difference between weak and strong declension.

Comment: Thank you both. Sure i will do it for my next question

Comment: If you want to understand word forms, always try to find a sentence in which that form is used. That will help you understand what grammatical form you are facing. What you are asking here is not a question about a word form, but a question about understanding the dictionary you have used.

Comment: Dear close voters: May I point out that a *why* question cannot be answered by a conjugation table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you found is:

feminine nominative singular:

> die/eine Bekannte
>
> Die Bekannte wohnt in Köln.
> Eine Bekannte wohnt in Köln.

feminine genitive singular:

> der/einer Bekannten
>
> Georg erbarmte sich der Bekannten.
> Georg erbarmte sich einer Bekannten.

feminine nominative plural:

> die Bekannten/zwei Bekannte
>
> Die Bekannten wohnen in Köln.
> Zwei Bekannte wohnen in Köln.

*"So why ... ?"*
Because it is not a normal noun, but a nominalized adjective, and because the rules for nominalized verbs, adjectives etc. are more complicated than the rules for "real" nouns.

A much better resource than Duden is Wiktionary: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Bekannte

Answer (score 2):

In calling *Bekannt-* *substantiviertes Adjektiv* you basically answered your own question. The correct ending can be determined by looking at a table of adjective inflection. However, I still want to try to get to the bottom of the problem.

If I understand your question correctly, the ending *-n* is giving you problems. Remember that this *-n* belongs to the declension of adjectives, not nouns! Coming from nouns, you might associate *-n* with the plural and the plural only. However, this is different for adjectives.

Looking first at the plural with the seemingly missing *-n*, we simply have the **strong adjective ending *-e***:

> Annas best**e** Freundin (singular), Annas best**e** Freundinnen (plural)
> Annas Bekannt**e** (singular or plural)

To get the **weak ending *-en*** in the plural, substitute the genitive *Annas* by an article with an ending:

> Annas beste Freundinnen > ihre best**en** Freundinnen
> Annas Bekannte > ihre Bekannt**en** (plural only)

Regarding the seemingly unexpected *-n* in the singular, it is the **weak adjective ending *-en***:

> ihrer best**en** Freudin (dative or genitive)
> ihrer Bekannt**en**